# vue.js: Using Chinese fonts in vue-material

Tags: css, fonts, localization, vuejs2, vue-material

I am using [Vue Material](https://vuematerial.io/) to build a multi-lingual application. How can I declare Chinese fonts to be used?

#### App.vue

App.vue loads the Material Design font locally.

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'
import './assets/material-icons.css'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
...
...
...
</script>
```

#### material-icons.css

At the top of this file, I have added the default/popular Chinese font for Microsoft and MacOS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Microsoft Yahei', '微软雅黑', '宋体';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Microsoft Yahei'), local('微软雅黑');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'STXihei', '华文细黑', '宋体';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('STXihei'), local('华文细黑');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

### Chinese font not used

This is a sample element with Chinese font

```
<div class="md-button-content">中文字</div>
```

Inspecting the element using Firefox development tool shows that the Chinese fonts are not applied

[image: font-family]

How can I ensure the proper Chinese font is used?

Reference: http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/